# Decomposition of finite abelian $p$-group into cyclic groups is unique. "Simpler" proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> **Theorem.** Let $G, G'$ be isomorphic finite abelian $p$-groups. Suppose $$G=A_1 \times \cdots \times A_k, \ G'=B_1 \times \cdots \times B_s$$ where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are cyclic groups of order (resp.) $p^{n_i}$ and $p^{h_i}$, $n_1 \ge \cdots \ge n_k>0$ and $h_1 \ge \dots \ge h_s > 0 \:$. Then $k=s$ and $A_i \cong B_i$ for $i=1,\dots, k$.

All the proofs I have seen of this theorem seem overly technical. They first prove that if two finite abelian groups are isomorphic, then the *number* of invariants is the same, by confronting the order of the groups $G(p)=\{x^p=e \mid x \in G\}$ and $G'(p)$ (defined analogously). Then they assume there is a $t$ such that $n_t > h_t$ (w.l.o.g.) and derive a contradiction by considering the groups $H= \{ x^{p^{h_t}} \mid x \in G\}$ and $H'= \{ x^{p^{h_t}} \mid x \in G'\}$, which are isomorphic and therefore should have the same number of invariants, but don't.

So I was wondering if I could prove it like this instead (I am omitting some steps to make it easier to read):

**Proof.** Assume w.l.o.g. that $k\le s$. I'm going to prove that $A_i \cong B_i$ for $i=1,\dots,k \:$ by induction on $i$. Since $p^{n_1}$ is the greatest order of any element in $G$, it must be the greatest order of any element in $G'$ as well, so $B_1$ must have order $p^{n_1}$. [For if $o(B_1)< p^{n_1}$ then no element in $G'$ has order $p^{n_1}$, whereas if $o(B_1)> p^{n_1}$ then there is an element in $G$ of order $>p^{n_1}$, both contradictions.]. Since they are cyclic of the same order, we conclude $A_1 \cong B_1$. This proves the base case.

Now assume the statement holds for all $i<d<k$, i.e. $A_i \cong B_i$ for all $i<d$. It is easy to show that $G/(A_1 \times \cdots \times A_{d-1}) \cong A_d \times \cdots \times A_k$ and analogously for $G'$. Since the quotient groups of respectively isomorphic groups are isomorphic, we have $$H=A_d \times \cdots \times A_k \cong B_d \times \cdots \times B_k \times \dots \times B_s=H'$$ But now we can apply the same reasoning used in the first part of this proof to show that $A_d\cong B_d$. The induction is complete, so we get that $A_i \cong B_i$ for $i=1,\dots,k \:$. The fact that $$A_d \times \cdots \times A_k \cong A_d \times \cdots \times A_k \times B_{k+1} \times \dots \times B_s$$ forces $k=s$, because the $B_i$'s aren't trivial by definition. $\square$

This proof is far more intuitive to me. I fail to see an equivalence between this proof and the "standard" proofs which I have sketched above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G=A_1\times ....\times A_k$ and $G'=B_1\times... \times B_s$ as defined in the question.

**Claim $1$:** First we prove that $k=s$. Clearly an isomorphism preserves the order. The solution of the equation $x^p=1$ in $G$ has $p^k$ solutions and $p^s$ solutions in $G'$. Thus, $k=s$, as desired. (According to your notation, we used the fact that $|G(p)|=|G'(p)|$.)

**Claim $2$:**  $n_i=h_i$ for $1\leq i \leq k.$
We proceed by induction on $|G|$. $$G/G(p)=\overline A_1\times....\times\overline A_{k'}.$$
$$G'/G'(p)=\overline B_1\times....\times\overline B_{s'}.$$

Where $|\overline A_i|=p^{n_i-1}$ and $|\overline B_i|=p^{h_i-1}$. Then we get that $n_i=h_i$ for $i\leq k'$  by induction. Note that $k'$ might be smaller than $k$ as some of the factors might be of order $p$ and they might be vanished in the quotient. Since both $s=k$ and $s'=k'$ by claim $1$, we get that $n_i=h_i=p$ for $i>k'$.

This proof is at least cleaner for me.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed cleaner. The use of subgroups such as $G(p)$, which contain elements of all the cyclic groups in the factorization, is inevitably neater. I should just get used to them.

Comment: Why exactly does $x^p = 1$ have $p^k$ solutions in $G$?