# Question about proof of uniqueness of decomposition of finite abelian $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

There is a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289287/decomposition-of-finite-abelian-p-group-into-cyclic-groups-is-unique-simpler) with a proof of the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** Let $G, G'$ be isomorphic finite abelian $p$-groups. Suppose
> $G = A_1 \times \cdots \times A_k$ and $G' = B_1 \times \cdots \times B_s$, where $A_i$ and $B_j$ are cyclic groups of order $p^{n_i}$ and $p^{h_j}$,  respectively, and $n_1 \geq \cdots \geq n_k \geq 0$, $h_1 \geq \cdots \geq h_s \geq 0$. Then $k = s$ and $A_i \cong B_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, k$.

There are two claims to be shown. First, that $k = s$ and then that $A_i \cong B_i$ for every $I$.

I'm just wondering about the proof for the first claim. The accepted answer is as follows.

> **Claim $1$:** First we prove that $k=s$. Clearly an isomorphism preserves the order. The solution of the equation $x^p=1$ in $G$ has $p^k$ solutions and $p^s$ solutions in $G'$. Thus, $k=s$, as desired. (According to your notation, we used the fact that $|G(p)|=|G'(p)|$.)

I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but as the question is several years old, I'm not hopeful that my comment there will be answered. I am just wondering the following: **why** is $|G(p)| = p^k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifying $G$ with $A_1\times\dots\times A_k$, an element $x=(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ satisfies $x^p=1$ iff $x_i$ satisfies $x_i^p=1$ in $A_i$ for each $i$.  A cyclic group of order $p^n$ has $p$ elements $y$ such that $y^p=1$ (namely the elements of the form $g^{mp^{n-1}}$ where $g$ is a generator), so there are $p$ choices for $x_i$ for each $i$ and thus $p^k$ choices for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_k)$.